# building /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build while compiling a kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, cross-compiling

I am cross-compiling 3.4.0 kernel for an embedded device. Then I would like to install compat-wireless drivers which require `/lib/modules/3.4/build` directory and sub-files. Could anyone explain how can I build that directory so that when I do `INSTALL_MOD_PATH=newmodules make modules_install` it would load `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build` directory as well? I would appreciate for a clear explanation.

I am using debian distro. I know I can install the kernel headers by `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, but I doubt it would be a good idea since the kernel sources might not be identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build is a soft-link to the directory where performed the build. So the way to do this is to simply do a

```
  make modules_install INSTALL_MOD_PATH=/some/root/
```

in the build directory of the kernel where /some/root is where you want your cross compile pieces to end up.  This will create a link to your kernel build path in /some/root/lib/modules/$(uname -r) ... verify that.

Now  when you build the compat_wireless drivers specify the kernel build directory in the Makefile as /some/root using the KLIB_BUILD variable (read the Makefile)

```
make modules KLIB_BUILD=/some/root/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
```

this should do the trick for you.

EDIT A

In answer to your comment below:

1. Keep "newmodules" outside the kernel directory it's a bad idea to put it in the kernel directory. so mkdir newmodules somewhere like /home/foo or /tmp or something.  This is one of the reasons your build link is screwed up
2. ALSO .../build is a soft link /to/kernel/build/location it will only copy over as a soft-link.  You also need to copy over the actual kernel source / kernel build directory to your microSD, using the same relative location. For example,

Let's say your kernel source is in:

```
      /usr/src/linux-3.5.0/
```

Your kernel build directory is:

```
      /usr/src/linux-3.5.0-build/
```

Your newmodules (after following 1.) is in:

```
      /tmp/newmodules/
```

So under /tmp/newmodules/ you see the modules installed in a tree like:

```
      lib/modules/$(uname -r)/
```

when you do an ls -al  in this directory, you'll see that build is a soft link to:

```
      build -> /usr/src/linux-3.5.0-build/
```

Now let's say your microSD is mounted under /mnt/microSD

then you need to do the following

```
      mkdir  -p /mnt/microSD/usr/src 
      cp -a /usr/src/linux-3.5.0 /usr/src/linux-3.5.0-build /mnt/microSD/usr/src
      cp -a /tmp/newmodules/lib /mnt/microSD/lib
```

Now you have all the content you need to bring over to your embedded environment. I take it you are doing the compat_wireless build on your target system rather than cross compiling it?

### NOTE

If your kernel build is the same as the kernel source then just copy over the kernel source and ignore the `linux-3.5.0-build`  in copy instructions above

Comment: I do `mkdir newmodules;` `make modules_install INSTALL_MOD_PATH=newmodules` then `make modules KLIB_BUILD=newmodules/lib/modules/3.4.0/build`. I see the files under .../build directory on the machine where I cross-compiled the kernel. then I load the kernel and modules to a microSD card (cp -r newmodules/* /mnt/miniSD4/). When I power the embedded board , `ls -al /lib/modules/3.4.0/build` does not output anything

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but some people will need this information.

I have spent many hours to figure out where `build` folder comes from, and why it is just a link when I compile my own kernel. Finally figured it out;

Linux kernel usually just links the `build` and `source` folders to the source folder.

But!

Arch linux (probably some other distros too); has a manual script for deleting those links, and adding (filtered) files to `build` folder.

https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/linux

I've extracted that script to work standalone (in a kernel source tree) here: https://gist.github.com/furkanmustafa/9e73feb64b0b18942047fd7b7e2fd53e