# /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build dir missing in openwrt

Tags: linux-kernel, openwrt

Whenever I am trying to install a new kernel module on top of openwrt (means in the built image) to make a hello-world kernel module it is throwing the following error.
make[1]: **

```
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/3.13.0-27-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

Makefile:9: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2

So how can I make build environment in my setup ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [building /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build while compiling a kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688138/building-lib-modules-uname-r-build-while-compiling-a-kernel)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/277008/473434

Comment: In openWRT linux-kernel is available in **build_dir/target-/linux-kernel/**.So from there how can I bring a /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build in final image?